# Which Oracle Join to figure out complex query

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two Oracle tables that I am looking to join but cannot think of the correct join to use.

Sales_Summary

```
Product Sales   Category1   Category2   Category3   Category4
123     $100    1           0           2           0
123     $200    2           0           2           0
456     $500    1           0           4           0
456     $400    5           2           4           8
```

User_Access

```
User    Category    CategoryNum
213     1           1
213     2           3
```

I tried doing a left join:

```
select sum(sales) from sales_summary ss
left join user_access ua
on (ss.category1 = ua.category where categorynum = 1)
or (ss.category2 = ua.category where categorynum = 2)
or (ss.category3 = ua.category where categorynum = 3)
or (ss.category4 = ua.category where categorynum = 4)
```

But it seems to duplicate results when a user has access to multiple categories.

With the SQL above I am hoping that for user 213 it shows total sales of $800 across all products based on their categories.

Category1/Category2/Category4/Category4 = distinct sales categories and are equal to CategoryNum

The Category value is kind of like a part of the category that they might cover (territory?).

Comment: You didn't say what your query is supposed to do. You should describe it and post sample output.

Comment: I am hoping that for user 213 it shows total sales of $800 across all products based on their categories

Comment: Please update your question with that information. Also, describe what `category` is vs `categornum` vs `category1` etc. What is their relationship?

Comment: _If_ I understand it well, the sum should be $900, not $800 ?!? Is this a typo ?

Comment: I think $800 because its the first 3 rows but not the third

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right. Just replace the `where` by `and` -- and you need a  `group by` clause in order to use the aggregate function `SUM`  (assuming you might have *several* users):

```
SELECT "User", SUM("Sales")
FROM  sales_summary ss
JOIN user_access ua
ON (ss."Category1" = ua."Category" AND "CategoryNum" = 1)
OR (ss."Category2" = ua."Category" AND "CategoryNum" = 2)
OR (ss."Category3" = ua."Category" AND "CategoryNum" = 3)
OR (ss."Category4" = ua."Category" AND "CategoryNum" = 4)
GROUP BY "User"
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73d3e/5

... however, this produces a sum of *$900*. Maybe you should check your requirements and the logic behind if the expected outcome *really* was $800...

---

<sup>Please note I've quoted all identifiers here as in your sample data, you used what seems to be case-sensitive column names **and** one column is named `User`, as so **require** to be quoted as this is a reserved keyword. Your mileage may vary though.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Getting a value of $800 with a `join` is going to be hard.  You can get the value using `exists`:

```
SELECT SUM("Sales")
FROM  sales_summary ss
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM user_access ua
              WHERE (ss."Category1" = ua."Category" AND "CategoryNum" = 1) OR
                    (ss."Category2" = ua."Category" AND "CategoryNum" = 2) OR
                    (ss."Category3" = ua."Category" AND "CategoryNum" = 3) OR
                    (ss."Category4" = ua."Category" AND "CategoryNum" = 4)
              )
```

The problem with this approach is that you don't get to specify the user.  You can specify one user with a `where` clause in the subquery.  Summarizing for multiple users will be hard.